# How do you add a UIToolbar to both views of the UISplitViewController?

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, uitoolbar, ipad

And then have it merged in vertical view? Here is an example from the IMDB app.

[image: http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/9669/imdb1.jpg]
[http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/5636/imdb2.jpg http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/5636/imdb2.jpg](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/5636/imdb2.jpg)

They did it perfectly and I would like to know how I can replicate it. Right now, I can't seem to add it to the left side of the split controller. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you don't.

What you have is two `UIToolbar`s and some code that moves the content of one onto the other when the `UISplitViewController` calls its delegate's

```
– splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:
```

method and that moves the items back again in the delegate's

```
– splitViewController:willShowViewController:invalidatingBarButtonItem:
```

method.

For example this might work:

```
– splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:
{
  // …
  NSArray *leftItems = leftBar.items;
  rightBar.items = [leftItems arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:rightBar.items];
  leftBar.hidden=YES;
  // …
}

– splitViewController:willShowViewController:invalidatingBarButtonItem:
{
  // …
  NSArray *rightItems = rightBar.items;
  NSUInteger lc = [leftBar.items count];
  rightBar.items = [rightItems subArrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(lc,[rightItems count] - lc)];
  leftBar.hidden=NO;
  // …
}
```